# Implementation of ++ operator in c++

Tags: c++, operators

How is the standard ++ operator defined in c++?(c++ 11)

For eg.

```
int k, i=3;
k = i++;
```

first assigns value of i equal to 3 then increments i.

Can somebody please explain how this is implemented?

Also, is a copy made of the variable?

Comment: If you find question to be incomplete, please comment. I am new here.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "how this is implemented", what are you searching for? The standard passage or how this gets done in asm or something?

Comment: It's implemented any way the compiler wants.  Effectively the statement is broken into two pieces.  But you need to beware, as the definition of when the `++` takes effect relative to *other* expressions in the overall statement is very confusing.

Comment: The standard passage, Thankyou .

Comment: So you'd like someone to quote the relevant paragraphs from the standard?

Comment: @HotLicks . I stumbled on sequence points and function arguments. But could not decide the output in many cases. Can you explain what happens at the compiler level?

Comment: They can be quoted if useful :)

Comment: I would highly recommend you read through this [operators tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

Comment: Relevant further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior

Comment: Compilers may have different implementations for this. What compiler are you referring to?

Comment: See **Item 6: Distinguish between prefix and postfix forms of increment and decrement operators.** from *More Effective C++* by Scott Meyers.

Comment: I avoid using `++` anywhere where the effects are not obvious.  Just like I throw in extra `()` whenever I'm a little unsure of the precedence rules -- it's not worth worrying about.  `++` was a performance optimization back in the 60s, but any compiler since maybe 1975 has known how to generate better code without.

Comment: (Background:  A few of the early computers that C was developed on had instructions to load and increment a storage location, with pre-increment or post-increment.  So prefix and postfix `++` were added to C (and the languages that preceded it) to take advantage of these instructions (since compilers were not smart enough to do so).  They have hung around mainly because they're handy for loop iterators, but any "optimization" they did is long gone.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard only defines what **it does**, **not how it should be implemented.**

As for the quote, you will find it in the C++ standard, section § 5.2.6 [ Increment and decrement] :

> The value of a postfix
>   ++ expression is the value of its operand. [ Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value —end note ] The operand shall be a
>   modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type
>   or a pointer to a complete object type. The value of the operand
>   object is modified by adding 1 to it, unless the object is of type
>   bool , in which case it is set to true . [ Note: this use is
>   deprecated, see Annex D . —end note ] The value computation of the
>   ++ expression is sequenced before the modification of the operand object. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
>   the operation of postfix
>   ++ is a single evaluation. [ Note: Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side
>   effect associated with any single postfix ++ operator. —end note ] The
>   result is a prvalue. The type of the result is the cv-unqualified
>   version of the type of the operand.

Comment: "With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix ++ is a single evaluation. [ Note: Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated with any single postfix ++ operator. —end note ] The result is a prvalue. The type of the result is the cv-unqualified version of the type of the operand."

Can you explain this more?

Comment: It means (to be short) that when the compiler needs to evaluate multiple function calls including a ++, it should not evaluate any of those function while evaluating the final (pvalue) result of the operator++ (it should be seen as an atomic evaluation is any cases). Doing otherwise is not permitted by the standard (at contrario, for example, a compiler is allowed to evaluate function calls during arguments evaluation in any order it wishes)

Answer (score 3):

When you make a overload for your class, you code it like this:

```
T& T::operator++() // pre-increment, return *this by reference
{
  // increment something, somehow
  // maybe there is local int i and you will type 'i = i + 1;' or '++i;'
  // so whatever 'increment by one' means in your case.

  // for type 'int', this function would result in (an instruction | a series of instructions)
  // that increment the variable by one.
  return *this;
}

T T::operator++(int) // post-increment
{
  T copy(*this);
  ++(*this);// pre-increment here seems logical
  return copy;
}
```

As you can see, a temporary is created and returned after the actual data is incremented. So the returned value is the old value while incrementing the actual value.

For built-in types, it works with the same logic. How to do it is up to the people who implement the operations and can vary. But it works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

the post fix ++, as in `i++`, is like this (in case of int):

```
int operator++(int i)
{
    int temp = i;
    i = i + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

the prefix ++, as in `++i` is like this (again for int):

```
int operator++()
{
    return i + 1;
}
```

You see why prefix ++ and -- are considered more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You have pre and post increment in C/C++ language. The value in pre-increment is returned before incrementing, post-increment returned the already incremented value.

Here is a excerpt from Wikipedia:

```
int  x;
int  y;

// Increment operators
x = 1;
y = ++x;    // x is now 2, y is also 2
y = x++;    // x is now 3, y is 2

// Decrement operators
x = 3;
y = x--;    // x is now 2, y is 3
y = --x;    // x is now 1, y is also 1
```

More info on [Increment and decrement operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)

GCC Internals explains this:

> The value of the single operand is computed, and the operand incremented or decremented. In the case of PREDECREMENT_EXPR and PREINCREMENT_EXPR, the value of the expression is the value resulting after the increment or decrement; in the case of POSTDECREMENT_EXPR and POSTINCREMENT_EXPR is the value before the increment or decrement occurs. The type of the operand, like that of the result, will be either integral, boolean, or floating-point.

[Unary and Binary Expressions - GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Unary-and-Binary-Expressions.html#Unary-and-Binary-Expressions)